# Is it possible to disable an EC2's IPv4 public hostname and still be able to resolve DNS queries from a private Route53 domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have an issue with a security report that reports an issue with my EC2 instance.

The issue states that I am using an invalid SSL certificate. The reason for this is that we are using a custom domain (example.com), but the security tool picks up the AWS generated public IPv4 DNS Hostname (*ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.region.compute.amazonaws.com*). The tool tries to connect with the generated hostname while the certificate is generated for the custom domain, hence the error.

Since we don't use the generated hostname, I wanted to delete it so the issue won't appear in the security report again.

However, I only know it to be possible by disabling "enableDnsHostnames" on the EC2's VPC. But doing this will break the ability to resolve DNS queries from a private Route53 domain linked to the VPC. As stated by AWS:

> For each VPC that you associate with a private hosted zone, you must set the Amazon VPC settings enableDnsHostnames and enableDnsSupport  to true.

Are there any other ways of deleting or changing this generated EC2 hostname?

Comment: Configure your TLS server to reject that name, that should be given by client during handshake through SNI, instead of answering with a certificate. Besides that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Could be ontopic for [sf] I guess. Other than that, did you ask your cloud provider for help?

Comment: Dear Patrick,
Thank you for your response!
You are right, Server fault should be a better fit for this question, my apologies.

I will try again to fix this in Nginx with SNI or contact AWS.